# Rails: undefined method 'to_sym' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) when running production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, braintree

I'm trying to run my Rails app locally such that it will point to the database used by the deployed app on Heroku. Using `heroku pg:credentials DATABASE`, I was able to get the information about the production database and use that to populate the production info in database.yml. However, when I run `rails s -e production`, I get the following error:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/braintree-2.68.2/lib/braintree/configuration.rb:59:in `environment=': undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/Robert/Developer/Git-Repositories/inspectx-live/config/initializers/braintree.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /Users/Robert/Developer/Git-Repositories/inspectx-live/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/Robert/Developer/Git-Repositories/inspectx-live/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Users/Robert/Developer/Git-Repositories/inspectx-live/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/Robert/Developer/Git-Repositories/inspectx-live/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Robert/Developer/Git-Repositories/inspectx-live/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /Users/Robert/Developer/Git-Repositories/inspectx-live/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /Users/Robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Robert/Developer/Git-Repositories/inspectx-live/bin/spring:13:in `require'
from /Users/Robert/Developer/Git-Repositories/inspectx-live/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I'm relatively new to Rails so I'm not sure what to do. I think this has something to do with Braintree integration, but I'm really not sure.

Edit: Here are the contents of config/initializers/braintree.rb:

```
Braintree::Configuration.environment  = ENV['BRAINTREE_ENV']
Braintree::Configuration.merchant_id  = ENV['BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID']
Braintree::Configuration.public_key   = ENV['BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY']
Braintree::Configuration.private_key  = ENV['BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY']
```

A note about braintree.rb: there was no private info to obscure. The above is exactly how it appears in braintree.rb. I didn't originally set up the Braintree integration, so I'm not sure if there was supposed to be private info in the ENV fields.

Comment: you should add for `nil::NilClass` to the title currently a little misleading. Also it just appears you are not setting the `Braintree::Configuration.environment` variable and that is where this error is coming from. Can you post the contents of `config/initializers/braintree.rb` obscuring the private info

Comment: Thanks for your response; please see my edits above.

Comment: Go to rails console, check what ENV['BRAINTREE_ENV'] is returning.
rails c production

Comment: Okay nothing major you just need to set `BRAINTREE_ENV` in Heroku. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Okay, I've ensured that the Braintree ENV keys shown by `heroku config` match those for my Braintree account. Also, since I have a production Braintree account, I've set BRAINTREE_ENV to "production". However, I am still getting the same error when running `rails s -e production`.

Comment: Your environment keys are not set correctly or you wouldn't be getting this error

Comment: Oh you are running this locally. Make sure you have those environment keys set in your environment. E. G.  `set BRAINTREE_ENV= YOUR ENVIRONMENT` then `export BRAINTREE_ENV`

Comment: Were you able to fix this? how did you fix it?